# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql when running from single jar

Tags: mysql, scala, sbt

I have a Scala test project which writes some information to a mysql database. I set up the project with sbt, and use sbt-eclipsify so I can run it from eclipse. I also used the sbt plugin sbt-assembly to create a single jar with all the classes I need from the dependent jars. I can run the program with no problem from eclipse and from sbt.

I run it from the single jar that sbt-assembly builds:

```
java -classpath target/test1-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar example.InsertDataIntoDatabase
```

but it fails with:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

My first thought was that sbt-assembly might have missed the mysql driver dependency, but I unzipped the jar, and found com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.class inside it.

Is there some other dependency it could be missing?

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to "uberjar" my app. In my case the problem was in loosing `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file during assembly process. So I needed to change assembly configuration to make the file stay in place:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) =>
    xs.map(_.toLowerCase) match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) |
           ("index.list" :: Nil) |
           ("dependencies" :: Nil) |
           ("license" :: Nil) |
           ("notice" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first // was 'discard' previousely
    }
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give an example of initialization code?

JDBC drivers usually require loading driver's class to call static initialization code and register it in the DriverManager. For MySQL this could be done with:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```